# Python modules import *

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I have a folder of modules called commands.

these modules each have a unique named function in them.

From the main directory, the one with the commands folder, I have a main.py

I can import all the modules with `from commands import *`

Is there a way to import all the functions inside all the modules without importing them individually. Even using a for loop would be fine.

Comment: Does `from commands import *` fail? That sounds like it should work. Also: is there an `__init__.py` file in the commands folder?

Comment: @JacobIRR that does not fail. Did you read the question?

Comment: Ah, now I understand. So the modules' inner functions are currently only available by calling `somemodule.somefunction()` instead of just being able to call `somefunction()` ?

Comment: @JacobIRR yes. That is what I am trying to fix, without importing them all one by one

Comment: You cannot pass a dynamic or evaluated value to an `import` statement, so I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a directory which have some python files (.py) and a `main.py` (inside the same directory) into which you want all functions of other files to be available. Here is a naive approach (a bad idea, really), and of course, watch out for name collisions:

Inside `main.py`:

```
from os import listdir
from importlib import import_module

for file in listdir('.'):   
    if file.endswith('.py') and file not in __file__:
        module_name = file[:file.index('.py')]
        # if you want all functions to just this file (main.py) use locals(); if you want the caller of main.py to have access, use globals()
        globals().update(import_module(module_name).__dict__)

# Functions defined in all other .py files are available here
```